# Connect mqtt client via web sockets with HTTPS from browser

Tags: node.js, https, websocket, mqtt, mosca

I would like to run a mqtt client on a web browser using web sockets with HTTPS. With HTTP, I have no problem. Here is the code on the web browser when using HTTP.

```
<script>
      var client  = mqtt.connect( 'wss://127.0.0.1:3000', {username:'test_user', password:'test_password'} );
      client.subscribe("mqtt/test");

      client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
        alert([topic, payload].join(": "));
        client.end();
      });

      client.publish("mqtt/test", "testing hello world!");
</script>
```

This is how I start the stand-alone mosca broker to use HTTPS on websockets.

```
mosca --very-verbose --key ./tls-key.pem --cert ./tls-cert.pem --credentials ./credentials.json --https-port 3000 --https-bundle --https-static ./ | pino
```

How should I change my mqtt client code on the browser to connect to the Mosca broker on websockets via HTTPS?

Comment: Use `wss://127...` instead of `ws....`

Comment: Molda, I tried that but I got the error `WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:3000/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled`

Comment: This could have something to do with the SSL certificate. How did you created, for what domain?

Comment: Molda, it is a self-signed certificate. The domain is just localhost.

Comment: Then try `wss://localhost:3000...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the other questions you have asked, the web browser has it's own list of trusted CA certificates, your self signed certificate will not be in this list so the connection is going to fail.

You can import your own trusted certs into your browser, but how to do this differs with each browser and you have to do it for EVERY instance of the browser so only really useful for individual testing.

If you need to allow members of the public (or browsers you can't install your certificate on) to connect to your broker then you will have to get a certificate from a recognised CA. You will have to either pay for this or use a service like http://letsencrypt.org

Comment: The browser will usually prompt the user that a particular page is unsafe when visiting a HTTP website if the certificate is self-signed. The connection shouldn't just fail without prompting.

Comment: Browser don't prompt when it's initiated from javascript

Comment: hardillb, I started a bounty, so I temporarily unmarked the answer to give new answers a chance. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 2):

You have problems due to the use of **self-signed certificate**
Instead - you can use:

1. service **cloudflare** as front (with https and wss in free plan). Read about [cloud flare](https://support.cloudflare.com)
2. Get Temporary sertificates from **letsencrypt** (has a free plans). Read about [letsencrypt](http://letsencrypt.org)
3. Get Trusted paid certificate

Comment: A quick point, Cloudfare won't work for native MQTT connections